# Using useState in server initialization not working in Nuxt js3

Tags: react-hooks, jwt, nuxtjs3

I have an application in Nuxt3,
On init page (first connexion or just manual refresh) useState is not working.
I verify if i have a token in the cookies, then i validate it on the backend, and then in the payload i retrieve the role and username to set in state ( i dont want to have it available in cookie or storage) but in Front vue login from setting the usestate value is working but not in server side, moreover the code after the use sate set is never called.

here my plugins/server-init.server.ts file

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin( async () => {
    const {REST_API_URL} = useRuntimeConfig();
    //console.log("server init");
    //to redirect after validate token
    const router = useRouter()
    const token = useCookie('token')?.value;
    console.log(' this is token');
    console.log(token);
    if(token!==null && token?.length > 0){
        console.log(' execute validation token');

        await useFetch(REST_API_URL + '/auth/validate', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
                'Content-Type': 'Application/json'
            },
            onResponse({request, response, options}) {
                // Process the response data
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    const payload = parseJwt(token)
                    console.log("payload")
                    console.log(payload.username)
                    //Dont know what happen from here
                    useState('isConnected', () => true);
                    useState('username', () => payload.username);
                    useState('role', () => payload.role);
                    
                    //this code is never reached
                    console.log('token is valid');
                    console.log(useState('username'))
                }
            },
            onResponseError({request, response, options}) {
                console.log('BIGGGGGGGG ERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRORRRRR')
                useState('isConnected', () => false);
                useState('username', () => null);
                useState('role', () => null);
                console.log('token is not valid or expired');
                if (response.status === 400) {
                    console.error('token expired or invalid');
                } else {
                    console.error('internal issue problem');
                }
                router.push("/")
            },
        });

    }else{
        console.log('No token registered')

    }
});
```

any idea ?

here simple case reproduction to see that only using useFetch, useState in a plugin does not work

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-czyl17?file=pages/index/index.vue

Answer (score 0):

So following this github issue :

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/18568 and

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/19382

my solution workaround was to do this

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin(async () => {
    const {REST_API_URL} = useRuntimeConfig();
    console.log("server init");
    //to redirect after validate token
    const router = useRouter()
    const token = useCookie('token');

    const isConnected = useState('isConnected');
    const username = useState('username');
    const role = useState('role');

    if (token.value !== null ) {
        await $fetch(REST_API_URL + '/auth/validate', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
                'Content-Type': 'Application/json'
            },
            onResponse({request, response, options}) {
                // Process the response data
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    const payload = parseJwt(token.value)
                    username.value = payload.username
                    role.value = payload.role
                    isConnected.value = true
                }
            },
            onResponseError({request, response, options}) {
                console.log('token is not valid or expired');
                if (response.status === 400) {
                    console.error('token expired or invalid');
                } else {
                    console.error('internal issue problem');
                }
                token.value = null;
                router.push("/")
            },
        });

    } else {
        console.log('No token registered')

    }
});

function parseJwt(token: any) {
    return JSON.parse(Buffer.from(token.split('.')[1], 'bas
```

e64').toString());
}

Use the useState outside the useFetch (or useAsync, useLazy etc...) and to mot use useFetch on server side